# Azure Virtual Machine SQL Server 2016 R service Error :Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script

Tags: r, sql-server-2016, azure-virtual-machine

I am using R services in SQL Server 2016 SP1 with machine learning Server 9.2.1 in an Azure Virtual Machine (I have installed both SQL Server and Machine learning server in Virtual Machine). Everything was going fine.

After changing few network configuration of Virtual Machine it shows error in R services. 1st it shows Launchpad service can not run. Then I try to modify SQL Server 2016 (in modification it shows r service failed). After modify launchpad working but if I execute any SQL R script:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
    X<-3'
```

I get this error:

> Msg 39021, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script. Please check the configuration of the 'R' runtime.
>
> Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   An external script error occurred:
>   Unable to launch the runtime. ErrorCode 0x80070718: 1816(Not enough quota is available to process this command.).

Comment: What networking changes were made and why?